# Continuous Function Satisfying $ f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) f ( y ) $

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be such that $ f ( x + y ) = f ( x ) f ( y ) $ for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $.
> If $ f $ is continuous at $ x = 0 $ then show that $ f $ is continuous on $ \mathbb R $. Also show that there exists a constant $ c \in \mathbb R $ such that $ f ( x ) = e ^ { c x } $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $.

Anyone please help me with the solution.

Comment: See in particular the **Related equations** section in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423494/291201) under  [Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(a)f(h) = f(a) \lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = f(a)f(0)$$

---

Letting $x=y=0$ gives $f(0)=f(0)^2$.

---

Case $1$: $f(0) = 0$.

Then, $f(x) = f(0+x) = f(0)f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)f(0) = 0 = f(a)$.

However, that provides a counter-example for the second part of your question, since there is no $c \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = e^{cx}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

---

Case $2$: $f(0) = 1$.

Then, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)f(0) = f(a)$.

We note that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, or else $f(x/2)$ would not be able to have a value.

We note that $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$, or else $f(x/2^n)$ would be $0$, but need to converge to $1$ because $x/2^n \to 0$ and the function is continuous at $0$.

Let $f(1) = e^c$. Verify that $f(r) = e^{cr}$ for all $r \in \Bbb Q$.

Then, use continuity to extend the result to $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems often start by finding special values.  What are the choices for $f(0)?$  If you choose one of them, the problem is trivial.  Consider the other and let $f(1)=a$.  What is $f(2)?$  What is $f(3)?$  What is $f(\frac 12)?  Can you extend this to all dyadic fractions?  Now use continuity to get all the reals.

Comment: "If you choose one of them, the problem is trivial." not really

Comment: @KennyLau:  once you find $f(0)=f(0)^2$ the two choices are $0,1$.  If $f(0)=0, f(x+0)=f(x)\cdot 0, f(x)=0$.  I think that is trivial.

Comment: but it actually proves the question wrong, since you can't find such a $c$ required in the question